# Decompiling for-each loop

Tags: java, bytecode

Decompiling the .class file of the following for-each loop produces interesting results.

*Source - Main.java:*

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = new String[3];
        int var3 = 3;

        for (String name : names) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

*Result - Main.class:*

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

public class Main {
    public Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = new String[3];
        int var3 = true;
        String[] var3 = names;
        int var4 = names.length;

        for(int var5 = 0; var5 < var4; ++var5) {
            String name = var3[var5];
            System.out.println(name);
        }

    }
}
```

The file was decompiled with IntelliJ IDEA.

- Why was `true` assigned to the unused `int`?
- Why was the `var3` variable redeclared?

Is this a mistake on behalf of the decompiler?

Comment: *"Is this a mistake on behalf of the decompiler?"* Certainly looks like one. Two, actually.

Comment: When I de-copiled using [JD Decompile] (https://java-decompiler.github.io/) , I don't see that : `public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String[] names = new String[3];
    int var3 = 3;
    String[] arrayOfString1;
    int j = (arrayOfString1 = names).length;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
      String name = arrayOfString1[i];
      System.out.println(name);
    }
  }`

Comment: The decompiler introduces variables with the naming scheme `"var" + counter`. Unfortunately there was an existing variable in the code with name "var3". As there is no `boolean` in the jvm, a single boolean variable is stored and processed as an int, somehow the warbled `int var3 = true` occurs. Its purpose eludes me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the bytecode level, there are no formal declarations of local variables, at least not the way known from source code. A method has a declaration of the maximum number of local variables existing at the same time or “slots” to reserve for them. A local variable comes into life when an actual value is assigned to it (by “slot” index) and exists at least to the last read of that value.

With these operations, it is impossible to recognize when a variable’s scope ends or whether two variables with disjunct scopes share a slot (compared to multiple assignments to the same variable). Well, if they have completely incompatible types, their assignments give a hint.

To help debugging, there is an optional code attribute providing hints about declared local variables and their scope, but this is not required to be complete and won’t affect the way the JVM will execute the bytecode. But here, it seems the attribute was present and has been used by the decompiler.

When I compile your example code with `javac -g`, I get

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
flags: (0x0009) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=7, args_size=1
     0: iconst_3
     1: anewarray     #2        // class java/lang/String
     4: astore_1
     5: iconst_3
     6: istore_2
     7: aload_1
     8: astore_3
     9: aload_3
    10: arraylength
    11: istore        4
    13: iconst_0
    14: istore        5
    16: iload         5
    18: iload         4
    20: if_icmpge     43
    23: aload_3
    24: iload         5
    26: aaload
    27: astore        6
    29: getstatic     #3        // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    32: aload         6
    34: invokevirtual #4        // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    37: iinc          5, 1
    40: goto          16
    43: return
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
       29       8     6  name   Ljava/lang/String;
        0      44     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
        5      39     1 names   [Ljava/lang/String;
        7      37     2  var3   I
```

The declared variables `args` (the method parameter), `names`, `var3`, and `name` were assigned to the variable indices `0`, `1`, `2`, and `6`, in that order.

There are synthetic variables without a declaration,

- at index `3` to hold a reference to the array the loop is iterating over
- at index `4` to hold the array length
- at index `5` to hold the `int` index variable that will get incremented in the loop

It seems, the decompiler has a simple strategy to deal with variables not contained in the `LocalVariableTable`. It generates a name consisting of the prefix `"var"` and the index within the stack frame. So it generated the names `var3`, `var4` and `var5` for the synthetic variables described above and didn’t care that there was a name clash between these generated names and the explicitly declared names, i.e. `var3`.

Now, it’s not clear why the decompiler generates an assignment of `true` for an `int` variable, but it helps to know that there are no dedicated `boolean` processing instructions in Java bytecode, but rather `boolean` values are processed the same way as `int` values. It requires appropriate meta information, like variable declarations, to understand when values should get interpreted as `boolean` values. Perhaps, the name clash described above led the decompiler to confuse the variable types afterwards, to eventually consider the value type not to be an `int` and fall back to treat it as `boolean` then. But that’s just a guess; there could be an entirely unrelated bug too.